# How do you copy sheets from one workbook to another using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to use the following code to copy sheets from my template file into and automatically generated worksheet.

```
 Set wb = Workbooks("Generated.xlsx")
For Each sh In Workbooks("TemplateASA.xlsx").Worksheets
   sh.Copy After:=wb.Sheets(wb.Sheets.Count)
Next sh
```

But I keep getting this error at compile:
Run-time error '9'
Subscript out of range

Comment: On which line is the error happening ? Did you properly declare your variables ?

Comment: Yes variable were declared.
The error occurs on this line:
For Each sh In Workbooks("TemplateASA.xlsx").Worksheets

Comment: Is sh defined as Worksheet ? If you go to debug window (Ctrl+G) and type `Print Workbooks("TemplateASA.xlsx").Name` what do you get ? And without the extension ?

Comment: Also, is TemplataASA.xlsx open? If not, you won't be able to access its worksheets.

Answer (score 0):

This will make it easier to find the problem - as above, I guess the workbook is not yet open. If I'm right, the `Set wbTemplate = Workbooks("TemplateASA.xlsx")` line will fail. This isn't tested - let me know if it doesn't work.

```
Sub CopyWorksheets()

Dim wbGenerated as Workbook, wbTemplate as Workbook
Dim ws as Worksheet

Set wbGenerated = Workbooks("Generated.xlsx")
Set wbTemplate = Workbooks("TemplateASA.xlsx") 'If this line fails, remove it and uncomment the following line
' Set wbTemplate = Workbooks.Open("TemplateASA.xlsx", ,True) ' Opens as read only
For Each sh In wbTemplate.Worksheets
   sh.Copy After:=wbGenerated.Sheets(wbGenerated.Sheets.Count)
Next sh
'wbTemplate.Close(False) 'Only required if you opened wbTemplate above

End sub
```